# Inherit database privileges snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to give access to all the current databases to a custom role in snowflake, is there a command with the type of

```
`grant CREATE TABLE on account databases to role DBCREATOR;`
```

that I can use? I know it can be done specifying the database name using the command

```
    grant CREATE TABLE on database <databasename> to role DBCREATOR;
```

Nonetheless if there are many databases it would be an issue since I would have to give access one by one and it will not work on new databases.

It would not be sovled transfering ownership since I want the role to inherit from the other one. I've managed to create the role DBCREATOR and create all the databases with this role and therefore the access issue is been solved.

Nonetheless there is another issue since I need a role that can only insert data in the database but can't drop the database, someting like

```
    grant all on database <databasename> to role DBEDITOR;
```

But there is still the issue of the database name. Is there any way to perform a "generic" grant that allows the role to have privileges on all the current and future databases? something like

```
    grant all on future database on account to role DBCREATOR;
```

A solution that could work would be

```
    grant role DBCREATOR to role DBEDITOR;
```

Nonetheless this would allow DBEDITOR to drop databases and have all the privileges of DBCREATOR which is not desired. And if it is made the other way around DBEDITOR will not be able to access the databases.

I'm trying to create a custom role in snowflake that can edit all the databases existing in an account.

Comment: There is no single command that will do this. However, it would be relatively trivial to write a SP that loops through your databases executing a grant per DB. You can then schedule a task to run the SP at a suitable frequency - so while the role might not have access the instant you create a DB, it will in the next x minutes when the task next runs

Comment: Yes, that's not the greatest solution, but it might work. Thanks.